# got disconnected on the remote linux server

Tags: php, pear, putty

my project on the remote server stopped working after i did the following

```
1> install putty
2> connect to the remote server using FTP details 
3> then in the root server installed pear using 
    $ sudo apt-get install php-pear
4> then i changed the path in php.ini
```

now the server has stopped working ... why? what happened? HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it might be *superuser* question.
Anyway, we need more details.

Assuming the server is running linux (/unix), check the logs - they will probably tell you why the server fails to start. Check both syslog (/var/log/syslog) and your server software specific log.

Comment: BTW you were not supposed to download it, better do
tail -f /var/log/syslog

try starting your server software and watch what is appearing in the syslog / output / or apache/lighttpd/nginx log.